# WebSphere App Server timing out while stopping (ADMU3060E: Timed out waiting for server shutdown)

Tags: websphere

We are having daily issues in our production environment where WebSphere Application Servers timeout while stopping. The error received is

> ADMU3060E: Timed out waiting for server shutdown

Below is some content from the error:

```
[6/14/20 3:30:21:650 CDT] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3201I: Server stop request issued. Waiting for stop status.
[6/14/20 3:50:21:719 CDT] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3111E: Server stop requested but failed to complete.
[6/14/20 3:50:21:720 CDT] 00000001 WsServerStop  E   ADMU3002E: Exception attempting to process server c0tcpc0
[6/14/20 3:50:21:721 CDT] 00000001 WsServerStop  E   ADMU3007E: Exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMU3060E: Timed out waiting for server shutdown.
[6/14/20 3:50:21:721 CDT] 00000001 WsServerStop  A   ADMU3007E: Exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMU3060E: Timed out waiting for server shutdown.
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerStop.runTool(WsServerStop.java:434)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:271)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerStop.main(WsServerStop.java:113)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

WebSphere Application Server version is 8.5.5.9 and the WebSphere SDK version is 7.0.9.30.

Comment: Hi, there can be many causes for this.  If you can get a thread dump when the problem happens, that will show which threads are still active and might provide a hint about something that can be tuned, such as a db transaction or some other remote invocation that needs a timeout adjusted.

Comment: Hi Bruce, we have taken thread dumps but couldn't find anything useful there. We tried taking the dumps for 2 consecutive days but none of the dumps had any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

The stopServer command has an optional timeout (in unit seconds) that you can specify.  See if using that helps, i.e., stopServer.sh server1 -timeout 20

[stopServer command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_stopserver.html)

(Sorry I didn't notice at first that your stop and fail message are indeed already more than 20 seconds apart, but still, specifying a longer than default timeout in stopServer might be useful.)

Comment: Hi Evan, it is actually getting timed out after 20 minutes, which is the default timeout setting.

Comment: Ah, I see the messages are indeed 20 minutes apart. Can you tell us more about the nature of the application, particularly does it tend to have long-running or complex transactions? A stuck transaction can also result in a stop not succeeding. In the thread dump(s) you have, any evidence of threads in a transaction wait?

Comment: Hi Evan, Yes I see some wait messages in thread dumps as below :

Comment: 3XMTHREADBLOCK     Waiting on: java/util/TaskQueue@0x00000000016B2E28 Owned by: <unowned>
3XMHEAPALLOC             Heap bytes allocated since last GC cycle=12664 (0x3178)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Java callstack:
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/lang/Object.wait(Native Method)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:196)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/util/TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:564)
5XESTACKTRACE                   (entered lock: java/util/TaskQueue@0x00000000016B2E28, entry count: 1)

Comment: How do I know for what thing this thread is waiting for ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to hint at a tx manager type wait.  Presumably you are entitled to IBM Service so you might want to call this in and they'll suggest a trace or other diagnostics to figure this out.